# Programmatically fill UIView with Rectangles of FLOAT height/width

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having problems with something that seems to be simple.
Programmatically fill an UIView with Rectangles of FLOAT height/width 
without any empty spaces between rectangles (rectangles should connect)
using the code below.

```
    int  WIDTH = 72(does NOT work);//80(works);//32(works);
    int  HEIGHT = 45(does NOT work);//50(works);//20(works);
    _cellSizeX = self.bounds.size.width / WIDTH;
    _cellSizeY = self.bounds.size.height / HEIGHT;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0,_cellSizeX, _cellSizeY);
    _cellIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    {
        cellFrame.origin.y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++, _cellIndex++)
        {  
            [_Image drawInRect:cellFrame blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];
            cellFrame.origin.y += _cellSizeY;
        }
        cellFrame.origin.x += _cellSizeX;
    }
    _blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    _Layer.contents = (id) _blendedImage.CGImage;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The code works fine, but only if there is a clear split into prime numbers relative to the
width and Height. E.G Width = 480, Height = 300.

```
The Primes of 480 are: 480= 2*2*2*2*2*3*5;
The Primes of 300 are: 300= 2*2*3*5*5;
And their common primes are: 2*2*3*5;
```

Which means i am fine with an amount of cells in row/columns:

```
8(actually 2*2*2)/5;
16 / 10;
24 / 15;
32 / 20;
...;
80 / 50;
```

But NOT e.g. 72 / 45.... The reason to put it simple:

```
480 / 72 = 6,6666667;
300 / 45 = 6,6666667;
```

On the other hand and example that would work:

```
480 / 32 = 15;
300 / 20 = 15;
```

So its a float vs int problem somewhere. But where ??!!

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: I didnt mention that i want to fill the whole screen. So rounding 6.66667 to 6 or 6.6 or whatever is not realy a solution for me because i would end up with empty spots at the right side and the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions, none are perfect because the reality is that the screen is not exactly divisible for some sizes, so if you make it perfectly even you will have some sub-pixel 'blurring' at the boundaries of rectangles.

**Idea 1:**

What you can do is keep a running total using a `float`, but clamp each rectangle boundary to `int`. That means calculate where the bottom and right edge of the rectangle will end in `float` then use the clamped `int` value, calculating the width and height from the previous bottom and right edges. In this case you will get uneven rectangle sizes but only ever 1 unit difference. For example 320 divided into 6 columns would be:

```
+-----+-------+---------------+
| idx | width | running-total |
+-----+-------+---------------+
|  0  | 53    | 53.3333333333 |
|  1  | 53    | 106.666666666 |
|  2  | 54    | 160.0         |
|  3  | 53    | 213.333333333 |
|  4  | 53    | 266.666666666 |
|  5  | 54    | 320.0         |
+-----+-------+---------------+
```

The same applies in the y-direction. To reduce the error even further on retina displays you can double your values (multiply by `scale`) then half them after calculations (divide by `scale`) so you only ever get 1-pixel (0.5 units) difference.

This approach is conceptually similar to a one-dimensional version of [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), which is a good related read.

**Idea 2:**

Calculate a suitable cell-size and round it **up**, then multiply by the number of cells to get an image slightly bigger than the screen. Then draw into this image using the integer cell sizes and scale the image down re-sampling it. This means you will get slightly blurred edges of rectangles, but no 'holes'.